# How to send photos,videos and other files via web sockets (Socket.IO) in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, websocket, socket.io

I have tried converting media into '**base64**' string then tried to send it. But I think for more long string there will be problem to send that string via web sockets. Kindly share better idea for that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm currently learning how to use web sockets in android, and trying to make simple chat app using socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options to do the same,

Peer to peer file transfer:
This uses XMPP mechanism of P2P file transfer and is only suitable for when both users are online. We usually recommend using cloud stored file transfer (see below) unless you have concerns / limitations on server-side.

Cloud stored file transfer:
This uses QB Content API to store files when sent by the user and to retrieve them when other user(s) are ready to download them. The user experience is seamless and allows the user to send/receive files even when the other user is offline, the other user can open the conversation any time and download/play the file.

On client side, typically you want to handle things like progress bars, thumbnails for photos and videos etc.

I read this on Quora and it works